# How do I use a custom module in my Heroku / Perl web application?

Tags: perl, heroku, buildpack

I have seen [**that post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187433/how-do-i-install-dbi-module-for-perl-on-heroku-machine) about a similar question, but the replies did not allow me to understand the process. AFAIK, Perl is not a compiled language. It does not make sense I would have to put all my code into a single app file... OK, I also must confess I am not a Heroku buildpack expert.

My issue is really simple: I have coded a Mojolicious application, my Perloku setup is working well, I am happy except I do not understand how to package my own Perl module into my app. And I can't trust there is no way of achieving this.

Could anyone give me advice about what I should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Heroku, [Perloku](https://github.com/judofyr/perloku) and Mojolicious for my personal website. I have a couple very basic modules I wrote to connect to the database and run single query.

I use the full size Mojolicious App. I put all my `.pm` files in the `lib` directory. Then in my Mojolicious app file `lib/NJEApp.pm`:

```
use lib 'lib';
use Projects; # This is a basic module that runs a single database query.
```

In the `script/StartApp.pl`. This file is called by the `Perloku` file in the top level directory.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../lib";
use Mojolicious::Commands;

#~ Start the Commands for the Application
Mojolicious::Commands->start_app('NJEApp');
```

For external modules, you can put them in the Makefile.PL in the `PREREQ_PM = {}` section

Comment: Thanks Nate, you rock. Your setup is exactly what I was looking for and although I did not set it up on my side yet, I am sure it will work great.

Comment: The funny thing, in the end, is to realize that in fact, the only action I had to take was to move my app into a subfolder in order for it to see the /lib directory! (For now, I am using Mojolicious::Lite)